# Disable interpreter in Freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I have to write a section inside a freemarker template containing a lot of syntax, that would be interpreted by freemarker but shouldn't. Is there something like a `<noformat>` tag telling freemarker not to interpret syntax in a given section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [#noparse directive](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_noparse.html) that should do what you want.

> FreeMarker will not search FTL tags and interpolations and other special character sequences in the body of this directive, except the noparse end-tag.
>
> **Template**
>
> ```
> Example:
> --------
> <#noparse>
>   <#list animals as animal>
>   <tr><td>${animal.name}<td>${animal.price} Euros
>   </#list>
> </#noparse>
> ```
>
> **Output**
>
> ```
> Example:
> --------
> <#list animals as animal>
> <tr><td>${animal.name}<td>${animal.price} Euros
> </#list>
> ```